# Call two event at the same time in initState

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

How to call two different events at the same time inside `initState` because these two events calling different api's. Whenever i put two events inside `initState` only one event is triggers. I seen some articles that it is not possible to call rather than creating two different bloc's. Any possibilities to calling two events at the same time.

```
  late HomeBloc homeBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    homeBloc = BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context);
    homeBloc.add(LoadRestaurantCuisineDishes());
    homeBloc.add(LoadRestaurantRecommendedForYouEvent());
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: add `super.initState();` below of the void initState() {

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil that doesn't work still only one event is calling.

Comment: `add super.initState(); below of the void initState()` useless tip, if you open initState implementation you will se it's empty, so no matter when to call `super.initState()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use transformEvents method of bloc with [rxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) like [mentioned in issue here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1853#issuecomment-715369388)

First, you should import rxDart and then add transformEvents function to your bloc like:

```
@override
  Stream<Transition< BookEvent, BooksState >> transformEvents(
    Stream< BookEvent > events,
    TransitionFunction< BookEvent, BooksState > transitionFn,
  ) {
    return events.flatMap(transitionFn);
  }
```

Comment: Bostanci But in this there are two events `LoadRestaurantCuisineDishes` and `LoadRestaurantRecommendedForYouEvent`

Comment: What this solution offer is: Non blocking event flow. So when you do this, one event is not blocking other one, but processed in order you call.